# Slick Json Column Support with MySql

Tags: mysql, scala, slick, slick-3.0, play-slick

I have a `Json` type column in MySql and I am using Scala with Slick.
How can I Provide support for the `Json` Column via Slick.

```scala
class SampleTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, ??)](tag, "test")  {

  override def * : ProvenShape[NodeReference] = (name, data)

  def name: Rep[String] = column[String]("name", O.PrimaryKey)
  def Data: Rep[??] = column[??]("data", O.PrimaryKey)

}
```

Any Help will be appreciated.
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a `BaseColumnType` to convert your `JSON` to a String while writing it to the database and parsing it to `JSON` while reading from the database:

```scala
import play.api.libs.json.{JsValue, Json}

private implicit val jsValueMappedColumnType: BaseColumnType[JsValue] =
  MappedColumnType.base[JsValue, String](Json.stringify, Json.parse)

class SampleTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, JsValue)](tag, "test") {

  def name: Rep[String] = column[String]("name", O.PrimaryKey)

  def data: Rep[JsValue] = column[JsValue]("data", O.PrimaryKey)

  def * = (name, data)

}
```

Comment: I have a column in Mysql of Type `JSON`

Comment: In my answer i used the scala Json classes, but you can use the java one (JSON) the same way. The important thing is to write your json to a string while writing it to a database and to parse it from a string while reading from the db. This is possible independent of your JSON library